# Best practices for collaborative web development in Mac environment?

Tags: macos, development-environment, collaboration

At my current job I've been the only web developer for almost 3 years. So for that whole time I just used MAMP on my own local machine. We have a 2nd developer that will be starting pretty soon and I need to figure out the best way to set everything up so we can both work on the same project.

All of the machines at our office are connected to a Mac OS X server. Is it possible to host our web projects on the server and have them be accessible via a short url such as exampleproject.dev?

The reason I want to have our web projects reside on our server is because it is always on. So if I'm not in the office I want our other developer to be able to access our web projects.

Also, I'd like to get some kind of version control software set up. Any recommendations? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hazard I've seen two companies fall into, and then emerge out of. Your other developer should also work locally (optionally against a common dev database though).

I would recommend putting Subversion or Git on the server. Just from personal preference and both of which work well with local environment setups, you have to push your changes into the repository before others will see them.

You can then set up an automated build system that pushes your code from your source control to the server for common viewing (if necessary).

From personal experience I would not recommend everyone developing against the same code on the same machine. People will break things and temporarily halt development for others as well as accidental code overwrites. It can't help but get ugly occasionally.

Definitely an advocate of: Work locally, commit often, but only once you're sure it's not going to blatantly break the site.

---

But — If you feel you still want to do the 1 dev environment at least make sure everyone is using an editor that prompts you (or updates) when someone changes the same file. As an example I use Sublime.

Comment: Ahhhh yes. Now that I think about it this is how we worked at my old job. We used VSS and developed locally on our own machines and then merged everything.

If we work from a common database, is that something we should have on the Mac OS X Server?

Comment: One slight variation I may suggest to this (based on other's preferences, this isn't my first choice) is to have separate developer environments on your remote server. Separate files, users, servers, etc. Then have a "staging" area that may connect to a shared DB for merging commits in before production. I also strongly recommend git.

Comment: @DustinMcGrew Yes you would put the common database on the server in that case.

Comment: @Aea Yeah that's fine too as long as the environments are separate. However it does get a little hairly if you have to install some common components. Also make sure you have *plenty* of redundancy since you don't want that server going down, or worse.

Comment: @b1naryj Good point, this generally depends on the platform you're using, e.g. if you're using python you have virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper. I'm going to assume the OP is using PHP however.

Comment: Would suggest a common Virtual Box VM is set up that mirrors the final live environment - each developer can then code against that. It doesn't take long to get these VMs up and once in this mindset you can then start running windows XP IE7 VMs to test cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

oh there are many ways. You could check out the thoughtbot dotfiles on github (https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles) which are meant for just that or you could investigate into different setups for tmux and session sharing. I'd recommend you get yourself used to git and homebrew because that's at the base of every common shared environment on the mac.